# How to compute adjacency score of a future action?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an assignment where I have to compute the adjacency score of a list while only being able to edit 3 lines of the code.

Adjacency score in the context of the function is as follows:
given the input `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`
The adjacency score would be 3 since there are 3 pairs with the same values. Namely the indexes: (1, 2), (2, 3) and (4, 5).

The goal of the function is to compute the adjacency score if one number in the array was inverted. The code produces the correct number for some inputs, and produces an incorrect number for other inputs. The input is always an list of 6 integers, 0 or 1
Here is the code:

```
    def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if (A[i] == A[i + 1]):
            result = result + 1
    r = 0
    for i in range(n):
        count = 0
        if (i > 0):
            if (A[i - 1] != A[i]):
                count = count + 1
            else:
                count = count - 1
        if (i < n - 1):
            if (A[i + 1] != A[i]):
                count = count + 1
            else:
                count = count - 1
        r = max(r, count)
    return result + r
```

Comment: "There is an error in the code somewhere..." If you're getting an actual error, please include the full error traceback in your question. If not, then please describe the current output and how that differs from your desired output.

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks, I have updated the question

Comment: What is an example of an input that causes an incorrent number?

Comment: *"while only being able to edit 3 lines of the code."* So is that the original code, or the code after you changed three lines? In other words, please post the original code, and your proposed solution as two separate code snippets.

Comment: @user3386109 the code in the question is the original unedited code

Comment: Is flipping a bit optional or mandatory? If it's mandatory, then the code gives the wrong answer for a list like [1,1,1,1]

Comment: @user3386109 it is mandatory and the list size is always 6. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Note that if the list size is always 6, and the numbers are 0 or 1, then there are only 64 possible lists. So you can try them all, and see what you expect the answer to be, and what the code actually generates.

Comment: @user3386109 I did just that and it seems the incorrect cases are when the list is all 0's or all 1's returning 5 instead of what i expect should be 4

Comment: @JoeGuida Yup, as far as I know, that's the only problem with the code. But it only requires a change in 1 line of code, so I might have missed something.

Comment: @user3386109 what change would that be ?

Comment: When attempting to understand other people's code, it often helps to throw a few print statements into the code to show how the variables are changing inside the loops. I think if you understand why the code is not working, you should be able to find the minimal correction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code, but the lines below should create the result, you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0])
pairs = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape = (len(a)-1, 2), strides = a.strides*2)

print(pairs)
print(np.sum(pairs[:,0] == pairs[:,1]))
```